# Bloquear función mail de php al detectar el envió continuo a un mismo email

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmailer, mail

Sinceramente no tengo ni idea de como plantear el código para el problema es simple:

Uso la función mail de php para enviar un correo electrónico para restablecer la contraseña, el problema esta en que no se como bloquear esta función cuando alguien "mal intencionado" sepa la dirección email de otra persona y este empiece a enviar a cada momento "restablecimiento de contraseña", la funcion mail tiene algo para evitar su mal uso? o no puede hacer nada para que detecte si se ha enviado un email hace X minutos

Comment: Quiza podrias guardarlo en la cache el timestamp de cuando fue la ultima vez y si ha pasado menos de 1 hora o algo asi no mandarlo

Comment: no tengo idea de como  hacerlo funcionar ya que no tengo una idea correcta de como seria el codigo

Comment: ¿Cuál es el proceso para restablecer la contraseña? ¿Puedes guardar en el registro del usuario fecha y hora en que se envió el correo? Si es así, entonces solo verificas que haya pasado un tiempo, digamos 30 minutos, para poder volver a enviarlo.

Comment: Si exactamente, cuando el usuario pide reestablecer contraseña genera un token y en la base de datos muestra la fecha en la que el usuario pidio la modificaciòn